# Application Insights Logs custom properties

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

I want to have a shared app insights instance that will hold all logs from different microservices running.

For each of them I am adding

```
        services.AddLogging(
            loggingBuilder =>
            {
                loggingBuilder
                .SetMinimumLevel(settings.LogLevel)
                .AddApplicationInsights();
            }
        );
```

But then in the azure portal I want to be able to search for logs for individual applications, for example using query like "applicationName = 'MyAppName'".

Is it possible to setup `loggingBuilder` to add in this custom property `applicationName` to be `MyAppName`?

Logging itself is done like

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    try
    {
      //whatever
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      logger.LogError(ex, "Meaningful information");
    }
}
```

Or is it a bad idea in general to share app insights instance and have all logs and telemetry available in 1 pile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ITelemetryInitializer to set role name

```
    public class MyTelemetryInitializer : ITelemetryInitializer
    {
        public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleName))
            {
                //set custom role name here
                telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleName = "RoleName";
            }
        }
    }
```

Then if its .net core register it

```
  services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer>(new MyTelemetryInitializer ());
```

Comment: The above works if used along with AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry extension method as well. For the standalone ILlogger ApplicationInsights provider, the following code shows how to add TelemetryInitializer. ```services.Configure<TelemetryConfiguration>(
        (config) =>
        {                            
            config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new MyTelemetryInitalizer());            
        }
    );```

Comment: Thanks! Close enough for me to make use of it :) And just in case - source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/app-map#set-cloud_rolename